# How to determine if brick wall can withstand weight of TV with 1m swivel arm?

Tags: brick, television

I live in a brick house in Spain and want to mount a large 65" TV on an internal brick wall. When I knock on it with my knuckles I get a hollow sound. I suspect they are perforated brick as shown below (I found some broken bricks on the roof of the house which could be the same).

The TV is 24kg (53 lbs) and the swivel arm is 13kg (27 lbs). However the arm can also extend 1m out which will put significantly more stress on the brick when fully extended. I have purchased Fischer Duopower 10X80mm wall plugs and screws.

How can I possibly determine whether this brick can withstand this weight? I am concerned that the brick or plugs will fail and the expensive OLED TV will smash into the floor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is on the other side on the wall?

Comment: I don't think we can answer that since you're not really sure about the brick wall. Think about getting 2 -  2x4's or 2x6's  and install them from ceiling to floor, bolting them to the wall.  How you bolt them depends on the wall. Then bolt the TV bracket to the wood.

Comment: On the other side of the wall is floor to ceiling walnut wood panels (decorative).

Comment: Ok so I should do a test drill? Presumably I can tell if its solid/perforated and the kind of brick based on the color of the dust.